# Lucene.net search engine

Tags: c#, lucene.net

I have a folder with 20 text files in it. and I wish to index this folder and search for any keyword among these files.

How can I do this in C#?

Comment: What about "not with lucene"? Any reason you willfully ignore what Windows offers (search service), jsut for adding anotehr software? Or do you have a reason that you prefer not to state?

Answer (score 4):

This is a nice introduction to lucene.Net:

- [Introducing Lucene.Net (CodeProject)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/IntroducingLucene.aspx)

It covers the basics of how to create an index, add documents to the index and finally how to search your index.

Comment: is this still up to date?

Answer (score 0):

1) Use this code to load all your file contents into a List():

```
var files = new List<string>();
foreach (var filePath in System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles("path_to_your_files")) {
    files.Add(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath));
}
```

2) Read my article on how to setup basic Lucene.Net search:
[Lucene.Net ultra fast search for MVC or WebForms site => made easy!](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/320219/Lucene-Net-ultra-fast-search-for-MVC-or-WebForms)

3) Instead of the static data in that article, use the data from your text files you got in step #1.

I hope that'll help!