# Efficient way to search for phrases that contain specific words

Tags: c#, string, search, collections

I need the most efficient way to do it in C#.

Assuming:

1. Collection1: `{"I am good", He is best", They are poor", "Mostly they are average", "All are very nice"}`
2. Collection2: `{"good", "best" ,"nice"}`

I want to search all `Collection2` items in `Collection1` and store the matching results in `Collection3`, so `Collection3` would be like this:

Collection3: `{"I am good", "I am best", "All are very nice"}`

Comment: Looks like you need an inverted index, look at how Lucene.NET does this, or just use that library.

Comment: I am wondering if you have done any research on the subject. For example in the related column here on the right there is [What .NET collection provides the fastest search?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009107/what-net-collection-provides-the-fastest-search?)

Comment: @EugenePodskal; Collection1 items will be like a phrase. Collection2 items will be all one word that will be searched in Collection1 phrases and then put the matching phrases in Collection3.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski; Can you write example in c# code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do it.

```
string[] Collection1 = {"I am good", "He is best", "They are poor", "Mostly they are average", "All are very nice"};
string[] Collection2 = { "good", "best", "nice" };

var Collection3 = Collection1.Select(x => x.ToLower())
                   .Where(x => Collection2.Any(y => x.Contains(y))).ToArray();
```

Comment: Not compiling in C# 2010. Can you write correct code please. This looks easy and good.

Comment: great, glad to help.

Comment: @p0iz0neR I'd like to point that this solution is `O(lengthOfCollection2*lengthOfCollection1*averageLengthOfStringInCollection1)`, while solution with lookup is amortized `O(lengthOfCollection1*averageAmountOfWordsInPhrase)` for lookup creation and amortized `O(lengthOfCollection2)` for **any subsequent** `Collection2` used. So if you need **performance**, and, especially if you need to conduct such searches with multiple different `Collection2`, then this solution is  an **inefficient** one, though a very concise one and handles not just words, but substrings/phrases as well.

Comment: @EugenePodskal; Well I have a list not more than thousand and for that it worked. I know this isn't the fastest one and will decrease performance for very large lists. Though its ok for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
IList<String> Collection3;

for(int i = 0 ; i < Collectio2.Count ; i++)
{
   foreach(String str in Collection1)
   {
      if(str.Contains(Collection2[i]))
      {
         Collection3.Add(str);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: That using nested loops. I want to avoid recursive loops.

Comment: in this case you need to use LINQ

Comment: I used Dictionary but it only returns TRUE or FALSE but not the index from ContainsValue function.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `Collection2` items are words in the usual meaning of that word [no pun intended], you can use LINQ [ToLookup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549211(v=vs.100).aspx) - that will give you a proper MultiValueDictionary analogue, and with that you can try something like:

```
var phrases = new[] { "I am good", "He is best", "They are poor", "Mostly they are average", "All are very nice", "Not so\tgood \t", };

var lookup = phrases
    .Select((phrase, index) =>
        new
        {
            phrase,
            index,
            words = phrase.Split((Char[])null, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        })
    .SelectMany(item =>
        item
            .words
            .Select(word =>
                new
                {
                    word,
                    item.index,
                    item.phrase
                }))
    .ToLookup(
        keySelector: item => item.word,
        elementSelector: item => new { item.phrase, item.index });

var wordsToSearch = new[] { "good", "best", "nice" };

var searchResults = wordsToSearch
    .Select(word =>
        new
        {
            word,
            phrases = lookup[word].ToArray()
        });

foreach (var result in searchResults)
{
    Console.WriteLine(
        "Word '{0}' can be found in phrases : {1}",
        result.word,
        String.Join(
            ", ",
            result
                .phrases
                .Select(phrase => 
                    String.Format("{0}='{1}'", phrase.index, phrase.phrase))));
}
```

It gives you both the index and the phrase, so you can adapt it as you wish.

But if your `Collection2` consists not of words, but of phrases, then you will need something more powerful, like [lucene.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074586/lucene-net-search-engine), something that can properly handle full text search.